# How to take the derivative of a matrix with vectors of constants on either side with respect to scalar?

Tags: matrices, statistics, derivatives

I am attempting to solve for the Hessian matrix of a one-way ANOVA model. The part that I am getting stuck on involves taking the following derivative:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial\Theta} \frac{1}{2}(y - \mu)'V^{-1}(y - \mu)$ where $\Theta_{2\times 1} = [\sigma^2, \sigma^2_A]$ are the variance components, $(y - \mu)$ is a Nx1 vector of the observed data minus the average, and $V^{-1}$ is the NxN inverse covariance matrix.

I found the following rule:

$\frac{\partial X^{-1}}{\partial\Theta} = -(I_p \otimes X^{-1})\frac{\partial X}{\partial \Theta}(I_q \otimes X^{-1})$ where $p$ and $q$ are the dimensions of $\Theta$.

However, this doesn't seem to work because it results in conformity issues. I imagine that I need some rule of the form:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial \Theta}kc'Xc$ where $X$ is a function of $\Theta$, $k$ is a scalar constant, and $c$ is a vector of constants. Is anybody familiar with such a rule?

Additionally, I have a formula for what $V^{-1}$ is if that is of any help.

Comment: Why not take the gradient with respect to $V$?  Does $V$ only have 2 degrees of freedom?